# how to run external django project different computer?

Tags: python, django

I developed a project on django, after that uploaded it on Github. I want to see this project any other computer, on django's development server but, when I downloaded the project and tried to run by python manage.py runserver command, localhost:8000 works but, I have  TemplateDoesNotExist at/  errors. How can I fix this?

Comment: Paste your error message traceback here.

Comment: probably the file access management is incorrect.

Comment: I'm new on django,how can I fix this @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have all files and directory that have before in initial project root directory.
also check .gitignore file in the repository